# angular.js integration with apache kafka

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache-spark, apache-kafka, message-queue

I am new to apache kafka and apache spark. I want to integrate the kafka with my angularjs code. Basically I want to make sure that, when a user click on any link or searches anything on my website, then the those searches and clicks should be triggered as an event and send it to the kafka data pipe for the use of analytics. 
My question is how can I integrate frontend code which is in angular.js to apache kafka?
Can I send the searches and click stream data directly to apache spark using kafka pipeline or do I need to send those data to kafka and apache spark will do polling to kafka server and receive the data in batches?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think (just cannot find at glance) there is Kafka client for front-end JavaScript. I cannot actually imagine stable setup when millions of producers (each client's browser) writing to the same Kafka topic.
What you need to do in Angular, is to call your server side function to log your events in Kafka.
Server side code may be written in a bunch of languages, including JavaScript for **[node.js](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node)**.
Please take a look for available clients at [Kafka Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients)

Update 2019: There are [several](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients#Clients-Proxy(HTTPREST,etc)) projects implementing REST over HTTP(s) proxy for producer and consumer interfaces. For example [Kafka Rest](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html) project ([source](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest)). Never tried these by myself though.

Comment: I do see, Kafka-node for node.js, however I was looking for client plugin for angular.js. Since kafka is scalable, so I wanted to make sure that, each client (i.e. producer) connect to the same topic.

Comment: Kafka built for sustainable stream of data entering topic and not for millions of opened/closed connections, what would be in client side acquisition scenario. You can prepare pretty simple feasibility test of this. Results will be interesting though.

Comment: So, basically there is no way, we can implement kafka client using angular.js . We need to send the REST calls from angular to the route handlers in node.js, which in turn will act as the kafka producer. Will it send the data using the kafka data pipeline to apache spark which will be consumer or  will it send the data using kafka data pipeline to apache kafka server?

Comment: Actually there are some websocket implementations that you could invoke from your controllers in Angular, that way you have full-duplex communication channels over a single TCP connection. But you still need a back-end to set up the websocket and delegate to Kafka.

Comment: I want to send REST calls from my angular to the kafka server. Is that possible. If yes, then can you give me the name of the REST service which I can use. http://docs.confluent.io/1.0/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html . I have got this kafka-rest implementation. Can I use this for my purpose.